# Switch between wireless headset and speaker on Windows 10

Tags: windows, bluetooth, speakers, headset

Issue summary: I can't have a proper **one-step switch** between PC speakers and wireless headset.

Most of the time I listen to my Windows 10 PC (music, games, etc) using speakers. But sometimes I need to switch to a headset.

So far I used a wired headset and it worked fine, the switch happened automatically when I plugged or unplugged the headset to the jack connector in front of the PC case.

I have no such luck with **wireless** (i.e. USB dongle based) headsets (tried with Logitech G533 and Plantronics Voyager Focus): I expected the on/off switch on the headset to enable or disable the headset over the speakers. That's not the case. I don't want to unplug the USB dongle from the back of the PC case. I tried shortcut based utilities like **AudioSwitch**, but they do **not work** for game sounds when **in-game** (confirmed with Diablo 3, World of Warcraft, Borderlands 2) although they work fine for Windows sounds and Winamp (when in desktop or even when in-game).

Question: what are the convenient one-step solutions (such as one keyboard shortcut or one on/off switch on headset button) that really work (even when in-game) to switch between PC speakers and wireless headset?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10:

1. Right-click on your sound control (speaker on the task bar at the bottom right of the screen)
2. Click on "Playback Devices"
3. Find your device and right-click on the device
4. Click **Connect**

Of course, make sure both your device and Bluetooth are turned on.

I'm personally using an LG HBS770 wireless headset that I originally purchased for my cell phone. I switch between my phone and the PC by using the above method.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm currently doing. Too many operations though, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice program called [AudioSwitch](https://github.com/sirWest/AudioSwitch) which makes this even easier, it's a one-click swap instead of having to open up the menu.

Comment: Last time I checked this does not work in-game, meaning that game sounds are not "redirected".

Answer (score 0):

Just click the sound icon on the system tray. You will see a little arrow beside the device name. A pop up menu to select the playback device will appear if you click it

Edit: you are looking for an ingame solution. Usually I just alt -tab and change the device. Also, it turns out some games aren't really good at handling the changes to the output DAC, which is your case. I just made it my habit to pick a device I want to use and stick to it while im playing...

Comment: Yes that's what I'm currently doing. Too many operations though, it does not answer the question.